how to panda concatenate on list with string dataframe names?
This may sound silly but I have list containing dataframe names and I am trying to concatenate those dataframes based on for loop or list comprehension or just pd.concat() them.
Code sample:
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 6], 'B': [7, 8]})


print(df1)
print(df2)

This concatenation works, that I understand
# ideally this is what I should have as list
users_list = [df1,df2]


print(users_list)

# this works that I know
print(pd.concat(users_list,ignore_index = True))

Below is my situation and this is not working. So how can I handle this ?
# but this is what I have
users_list2 = ['df1','df2']

print(users_list2)


# but this is what I am trying to achieve as I have list of dataframe names due to some processing
print(pd.concat(users_list2,ignore_index = True))

So I am basically facing error due to users_list2 containing names/string dataframes and not the dataframes.
Appreciate any help here.

The problem is that you have two strings in users_list2. If you want to concatenate the dataframes based on that list, first you must evaluate the strings to variables.
You can use the following code:
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 6], 'B': [7, 8]})

users_list2 = ['df1','df2']

dataframes = pd.concat([eval(df_name) for df_name in users_list2])

I hope this helps.
Best regards

Yes this is exactly what I was looking for but I was trying {} for evaluating strings. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Glad it helped. Best regards

If I got you right:
users_list2 = [df1,df2]
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for df in users_list2:
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, df],ignore_index = True)


yes this is what I am trying to do but even I tried this before posting on SO and got an error and even now I just pasted your code & ran and still got an error: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

I corrected my code. Try again

the situation is I have list of dataframe names which is users_list2 = ['df1','df2'] so it cant be users_list2 = [df1,df2] that you are using.
